# Openstack Octavia - How to Load balance Web Applications

Tags: load-balancing, openstack

I am trying to fire up Octavia Load balancer to balance user requests over 5 servers running a web application. I have been searching for a tutorial on this as the OpenStack API does not give a detailed guideline.

A brief background to my current OpenStack setup. We have OpenStack installed using juju and Octavia was installed also using juju, this link https://jaas.ai/octavia/15 and this is the overlay bundle used https://github.com/openstack-charmers/openstack-bundles/blob/master/stable/overlays/loadbalancer-octavia.yaml. After this installation, to bring Octavia up is my problem. I followed this tutorial https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/install/install-ubuntu.html, but it seems to be doing what the juju commands did, so I am at a loss to how I am supposed to start up an Octavia instance.

Can someone point me to a resource that explains this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

glad to have you trying out Octavia.

The document you are looking for is the load balancing cookbook: [https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/user/guides/basic-cookbook.html](https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/user/index.html)

It is included in our end-user section of the Octavia documentation here: https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/user/index.html

Michael

Comment: Thank you. Will check them out.